# Ant <chdir> task?

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

How can I change the current working directory in Ant?

The [Ant documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/) has no `<chdir>` task, and it seems to me that it is the best practice NOT to change the current working directory.

But let's assume we still want to do it - how would you accomplish that? Thanks!

Comment: There is only `basedir` (see http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html).  Once it's set for a build you can't change it.  Perhaps explain what it is you're trying to do?

Comment: Several ANT tasks have a dir attribute for setting directory in which a particular action should occur.

Comment: @martinclayton I am trying to change the current working directory. My localized personal little problem will be solved one way or another - but the question remains: Is there some trick by which one could change the current working directory?

Comment: I should have prefixed my first comment with "Ant has no concept of current working directory that you can change mid-build."  But you can "re-enter" (i.e. self-invoke Ant) with a different directory if you wish.  And as Mark mentions, there are plenty of tasks that can be configured to operate in a specified directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following Mark O'Connor's hint in the question comments, I came up with the following solution:

```
<project name="cwd" default="parent">
    <target name="parent">
        <echo message="Current working directory in parent: ${basedir}" />
        <ant antfile="../build.xml" dir="subdir" target="subDirTarget"
            inheritAll="true" inheritRefs="true" /> 
    </target>

    <target name="subDirTarget">
        <echo message="Current working directory in subDirTarget: ${basedir}" />
    </target>
</project>
```

This works - output:

```
Buildfile: C:\Sandbox\parent\build.xml
parent:
     [echo] Current working directory in parent: E:\Sandbox\parent
subDirTarget:
     [echo] Current working directory in subDirTarget: E:\Sandbox\parent\subdir
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
```

I also tried using [Ant-Contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/)'s `<var>` task to change `basedir`, but that seemed to have no effect.